# I am having this ERR! code ELIFECYCLE error while running npm start locally?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am newbie to React and trying to build my first React App. My App was running fine till last night. When I open my project in the morning and ran npm start or yarn start command, it gave me error - ***ERR! code ELIFECYCLE***

I tried to close app and tried to run command again as per one of the solution given in the forum. But, that didn't work.

> " *react-scripts start
>
> 'react-scripts' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.
>
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>
> npm ERR! errno 1
>
> npm ERR! my-portfolio@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
>
> npm ERR! Exit status 1
>
> npm ERR!
>
> npm ERR! Failed at the my-portfolio@0.1.0 start script.
>
> npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely
>   additional logging output above.
>
> "*

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing the `react-scripts` package. You need to do an `npm install`.

Answer (score 0):

If `npm install` doesn't fix your problem it's probably because npm install is not able to properly complete the installation. Try this instead:

Delete the `node_modules` folder and
delete the `package-lock.json` file or the `yarn.lock` file

```
Run npm install
Run npm i -S react-scripts
Run npm start
```

Good luck!

Comment: To delete node_modules I highly recommend [npkill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npkill) just type `npx npkill`